# Windows Store Application Facebook SDK Integration

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm novice when it comes to using API's with C# apps, and I decided to start a windows 8 Modern UI application.  I've looked for information about how to integrate facebook into a project using the facebook API, and I found some useful answers, but some things are still unclear to me...

I've not found any official Facebook API for C#, I created an developer acount on Facebook but when i want to create a project using it, there is no choice for a c# application.

I've searched the Internet and found this : https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows8-sample

I downloaded it and put the app's id I got from Facebook on it, but it doesn't work.  My question is simple: Is there any official API with documentation or a website where I can get real and exact information for it?

Comment: The SDK located on github.com is official.  The SDK you should be using is the one you located.

Answer (score 4):

The [Official SDK from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) is only for PHP, Javascript, iOS and Android.

For the .NET world, there is the [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org) which you have already found. You can do everything with it, including full Windows 8 Apps with Facebook integration.

The main site is at http://CSharpSDK.org/

Comment: okay it's working now, sorry for my useless post, i just had to wait a little bit. i think that facebook need time to make your appid activated. thank you some much for you answer Jim