# integrate facebook comment box to xaml (windows 8 store apps) C#

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, comments, windows-store-apps

I am trying to embed Facebook comment box in a windows 8 store app. Is it possible to directly integrate the comment box or are there any other alternative solutions?

What I am trying now >>>> create a web page and add the Facebook comment box to webpage. Then access the webpage that I created through a Webview control. But when I try to login to Facebook using the comment box's link, it will not open the login dialogue inside the webview but it opens the browser where my windows 8 Store app pulled to the background.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the Facebook API, as [recommended by another SO user answering a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932330/windows-store-application-facebook-sdk-integration)

[There is a Facebook API for Windows 8](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/windows/)

[You can find an example on Github here](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows8-sample)

I haven't tried this API, but did a WPF app using a similar API and it's usually straight forward.

If you would like to, and I know you didn't ask about that - this is just a tip, there is a web authentication broker in the WinRT API's to enable single sign on (SSO) connections to OAuth providers like Facebook etc.

[You can find a sample here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

Hope this helps, best of luck.